# ASP.net in Visual STudio 2010. Working with dropdown lists and a submit button

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new the Visual Studio 2010.  I have a drop down list that pulls a list of data from a basic select from statement.  There are only 4 choices in the drop down list.. let's say it's just apple, banana, pear, and grapes.  How do I make it so when I pick apple it redirects to one page, but if I select banana it redirects to a different one?  Currently I have the submit button directing to one page but how do I make it so that it dynamically changes based on the user selection?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the onchange event of the select element:

```
function getComboA(sel) {
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
    // decide what to do with value for example
    if(value=='apple')
      window.location='pages.aspx';

}

<asp:dropDownList onchange="getComboA(this);" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

by this time you don't need render any control asp.

option 1

```
<select id="myselect" onchange="myfunction();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="pear">pear</option>
    <option value="grapes">grapes</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
        var value = $("#myselect").val();
        switch (value) {
            case "apple":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
            case "banana":
                window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
                break;
            case "pear":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
            case "grapes":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

option 2

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myselect" onchange="myfunction();" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="apple" Value="apple" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="banana" Value="banana" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="pear" Value="pear" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="grapes" Value="grapes" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
        var value = $("#<%= myselect.ClientID %>").val();
        switch (value) {
            case "apple":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
            case "banana":
                window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
                break;
            case "pear":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
            case "grapes":
                window.location = "http://www.apple.com/";
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

option 3 (need postback)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myselect" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myselect_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="apple" Value="apple" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="banana" Value="banana" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="pear" Value="pear" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="grapes" Value="grapes" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

in code behind .cs

```
protected void myselect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (myselect.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "apple":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.apple.com/");
            break;
        case "banana":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.apple.com/");
            break;
        case "pear":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.apple.com/");
            break;
        case "grapes":
            Response.Redirect("http://www.apple.com/");
            break;
    }
}
```